# What is the name of the music at S1E3 09m:07s of Domestic Girlfriend?

Tags: music, domestic-na-kanojo

Anyone knows the music playing in the background of *Domestic girlfriend* Season 1, episode 3 and 09m:07s?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for 夏生の想い, or [Natsuo no Omoi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INuWVMSvV4M)

Comment: Youtube says "This video is unavailable". Can you mail me if it's working for you ?